# Is there a way to "inject" an event into an existing .ICS calendar feed?

Tags: calendar, icalendar

Our company uses a complex booking software package. There's a few people who are authorised to use this. Everyone else can view a live calendar that the software publishes an ICS feed for in the calendar app of their choosing.

There's one problem with it (and yes I've asked the developers) - you can't have an "all day" event in the software. So if I want to add an all day event in the calendar as an informational thing at the top of the day in the calendar - I can't do it.

Take a look at an all day event in something like Outlook and you'll understand what I mean. It's an entry at the top of the day, above the hours for the day. They serve as usual reminders of Public Holidays or special days where the area might be busy etc.

The only way I can get an all day event, is to actually book the whole day out in a venue - which would then prevent me booking that venue in reality.

I was wondering if there was a way I could "hijack" the published feed and insert any events into it? Or modify existing events with a special criteria to change them to "all day" events?

Answer (score 0):

Without actually changing the original system you are left with 'hack' type possibilities:

Internal:

1. can you add a dummy venue - being the info venue?  So you can add
   all day info without affecting real venue bookings
2. Or explore whether you can have a zero duration event beginning of
       day, midday? with info?

external:

1. You could have an alternate url that fetches the main ics feed and
   adds the all day info events.  People then subscribe to the
   alternate url.
2. Or you could have a separate informational event url that just has those
   all day info events and ask people to subscribe to those too.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response!  

Your Internal solutions 
1. unfortunately won't work, because the system doesn't seem to translate events into "all day" events - even if they are from 00:00 to 24:00 - they will show up like that, rather than an all day event.
2. The second option is what we are now doing: creating events in an "info" venue at 06:00 to 06:30.  Not the same but close!